# version control in iphone programming

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use version control in xcode and i am unable to create branch,trunk,and tag directories in terminal. can any one please help me ...

Comment: What did you try so far? Simple `svn mkdir ^/{trunk,branches}` does not work? What does it mean that you are “unable to create” them? Somebody comes to your office and stops you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Apple link to SVN](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html) link should be helpful.